# C++ Function causing Application Crash

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, matrix

I am currently puzzled as to why this C++ function keeps crashing my current Program.

As you will probably see I have come from a Java background and am now extremely keen on learning a language like C++.

This function is supposed to populate a 2d array of the type Node with a new Node at each position. I want to use a 2D array and not a vector because this is for a Sudoku Solver that I am attempting to write.

When I build and run the application merely crashes and says:

"SudokuSolver.exe has stopped working"
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BEX
  Application Name: SudokuSolver.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    55283d72
  Fault Module Name:    MSVCR110.dll
  Fault Module Version: 11.0.51106.1
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5098858e
  Exception Offset: 000a326c
  Exception Code:   c0000409
  Exception Data:   00000007
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.768.101
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 332b
  Additional Information 2: 332b994896f66a7b5d5fb96032f7fbd2
  Additional Information 3: 2fa1
  Additional Information 4: 2fa12dec635ddb7f7a8e7c8690abd06a

I am using Eclipse to code in C++.

Below is the Function in question.

```
void fillArray(Node grid[][matrixSizeY], string filePath) {

    int index = 0;

    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open(filePath);

    // Check for Errors
    if (inFile.fail()) {
        cerr << "Error Opening File" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    while (!inFile.eof()) {

        string line;

        getline(inFile, line);

        // Get a Vector of each character in the String
        vector<string> data;
        Utilities::splitEachCharacter(line, data);

        printVect(data);

        for (int i = 0; i < matrixSizeY; i++) {

            string temp = data[i];

            int value = stoi(temp, nullptr, 0);

            Node node(index, i, value);

            grid[index][i] = node;
        }

        data.clear();
        line = "";
        index++;
    }
}
```

I feel like I should maybe make an array of pointers to new Objects using a function that I call for each position in the Matrix,  something like this perhaps:

```
Node* getNode(int x, int y, int data) {

    Node *node = new Node(x, y, data);

    return node;

}
```

But I am really confused as to how to make an array of pointers like this. Some help and clarifications/explanations would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

The Function is now working, I made the Following Change:

```
// Function Definition
void fillArray(Node (&grid)[matrixSizeX][matrixSizeY], string filePath);
```

Comment: "want to use a 2D array and not a vector because this is for a Sudoku Solver that I am attempting to write." <-- doesn't make sense what are 2D Vectors for :p anyway first of all you should narrow down where your program crashes using a debugger as you're using a couple of own functions in there we can't really tell where the error is

Comment: `while (!inFile.eof())` is wrong, it should be `while (getline(inFile, line))`. Don't use raw pointers and new. Just return node by value if it's small.

Comment: Thank you guys for you helpful comments! Each one help me figure out what was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception code corresponds to Stack buffer overflow. This may indicate some nested call without end or any excess in local variables size that can be solved with compilation parameters. Indeed, the lines

```
Node node(index, i, value);
grid[index][i] = node;
```

imply at minimum the use of copy constructor of node structure. Please note that you pass Node grid[][matrixSizeY] by value, not reference (your work is losed when returning) and the copy will charge the buffer if the array is big. Next, you dont specify the first array dimension (that's legal? I'm very unsure of that since I think that only last dimension may be optional).

Comment: Thank you for you help, I realized I was doing quite a few things incorrectly, learning C++ after Java is proving to be quite tricky. I feel I should have started with the former instead. Please see my edit to see my changes if you are interested.